# How to join pandas dataframe so that seaborn boxplot or violinplot can use a column as hue?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a dataframe with multiple columns, and I can easily use seaborn to plot it in a boxplot (or violinplot, etc), like this:

```
data1 = {'p0':[1.,2.,5,0.], 'p1':[2., 1.,1,3], 'p2':[3., 3.,2., 4.]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data1)
sns.boxplot(data=df1)
```

[image]

What I now need is to merge this dataframe with another one, so that I can plot them in a single boxplot, just as is done here: http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/grouped_boxplot.html

I have tried adding a column and concatenating. The result seems ok

```
data1 = {'p0':[1.,2.,5,0.], 'p1':[2., 1.,1,3], 'p2':[3., 3.,2., 4.]}
data2 = {'p0':[3.,1.,5,1.], 'p1':[3., 2.,3,3], 'p2':[1., 2.,2., 5.]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data1)
df1['method'] = 'A'
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)
df2['method'] = 'B'
df_all = pd.concat([df1,df2])
sns.boxplot(data=df_all)
```

This works, but it plots together data from methods A and B. However this fails:

```
sns.boxplot(data=df_all, hue='method')
```

because I then need to specify x and y. If I specify x as `x=['p0', 'p1', 'p2']`, them the 3 columns are averaged. 
So I guess I can merge the dataframes in a different way so that its representation is simple with seaborn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what would be needed here for this to work in a simple way would be to have a dataframe like so:

> value method p
>
> 1.0   A     p0
>
> 2.1   A     p0
>
> 3.0   A     p1
>
> 1.3   B     p0
>
> 4.3   B     p1

Then you could get what you want with `sns.boxplot(data=df, hue='method', x='p', y='value')`

I'm looking into how to merge df1 and df2 easily into a data frame like this one, but I'm not really a pandas expert.

Edit: Figured it out, need to use the `melt` method:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1.melt(id_vars='method', var_name='p'),
                 df2.melt(id_vars='method', var_name='p')],
                 ignore_index=True)
sns.boxplot(x='p', y='value', hue='method', data=df3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> `sns.boxplot(data=df1, hue='method')`

just contains the information from the first dataframe (`df1`). If you just use `df1`, all the rows in `df1["method"]` have the same value ("A"), so the color will be the same for all of them.

An option would be to concatenate both dataframes; for example:

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df2])
sns.boxplot(data=result, hue='method')
```

UPDATED QUESTION:

If you pass a `data=pandas.Dataframe()` as argument, you should then define the `x` and `y` arguments with the column names of the dataframe.

Comment: Oh! I am so sorry. That was I typo. I line was missing. I've edited the question.

Comment: If you use `hue` seaborn requires to specify `x` and `y`. This is my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,2,sharey=True)
for i,g in enumerate(df_all.groupby(by=df_all.method)):
    sns.boxplot(g[1],ax=ax[i])
    ax[i].set_title(g[0])
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: you can loose the loop with tidy data: `seaborn.factorplot(data=df3.stack().reset_index(), x=xcol, y=ycol, hue=huecol, col='method')`

Comment: @PaulH: thanks very much for your comment. I'm not sure how this would work. Would you write up an answer using this method?